# Is "funds" a plural or singular noun?

Tags: grammar, singular-vs-plural, uncountable-nouns, countability, countable-nouns

The dictionary enlists it as "fund," but the word "funds" is used quite often and it means money (Ok, it can have other meanings as well. I get that)

Do I say, then,

> how much funds did the organization raise? (because I am talking about
>   an amount)

or

> how many funds did the organization raise?

I don't care if you're a native speaker, but please answer this if you're sure about the correct usage. Many thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Fund** is a *countable* noun meaning *an amount of money kept for a specific purpose*. There can be many different funds.

**Funds**, in addition to its meaning as the plural of *fund*, is used as an *uncountable* noun synonymous with "money." Thus, it would take the *comparative adjective* "much" just as "money" does:

> How much funds did the organization raise?

However, the construction is awkward, and would seldom be used by a native speaker. Instead, we would say "How much *money?*"

*Funds* takes the plural when it serves as the subject:

> The funds are not sufficient to the task.

When all is said and done, *funds,* when used to connote *money,* is a plural uncountable noun.

Comment: Very much so... I wouldn't use "funds" in this way. I'd use "money" all the way.

Comment: Thank you, and I agree. It sounded off to me too. The problem is that "funds" is such a key word for what I am writing.

Comment: @Asaf - You have many options: _capital, assets, money,_ etc., depending upon the context.

Comment: And then there's *funding*... I think *in funds* works ok in that sentence though maybe still seems a little weird. Try *funding* though.

Comment: If it's the subject of a verb, though, it takes the plural conjugation: "The funds are insufficient".

Comment: @Acccumulation Yes indeed. What a very peculiar noun this is.

Comment: In a context where we normally say "funds" and "funding", I want to say "I'll use this funds to attend the conference" but hesitate to do so.  In this context "this funds" means "this block of money provided by a funding agency for a specific purpose". What's the best alternative to "this funds"?  "This funding"?

Comment: @Ryo - In your instance, "I'll use *these* funds" is idiomatic and correct.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/funds?q=Funds), "funds" is a plural noun

[image]

which means

> money, often money for a specific purpose.

The dict also gives these examples

> I’m short of/low on funds at the moment.
>
> The Brownies sold cookies to raise funds for their troop.

The second example use "funds" the same way as you example.